# use "!" to execute commands with same parameter in a script

Tags: bash, scripting

In a shell, I run following commands without problem,

> ls -al
>
> !ls

the second invocation to `ls` also list files with `-al` flag. However, when I put the above script to a bash script, complaints are thrown,

`!ls, command not found.`

how to realise the same effects in script?

Comment: It would be better to just copy the previous line, and not rely on command history inside a script.

Comment: is it possible to do this with different commands? For example mkdir + cd?

Comment: Although you can enable this, this is bad programming practice. It will make your scripts error-prone and hard to understand. There is a reason it is disabled by default. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to turn on both command history and !-style history expansion in your script (both are off by default in non-interactive shells):

```
set -o history
set -o histexpand
```

The expanded command is also echoed to standard error, just like in an interactive shell. You can prevent that by turning on the `histverify` shell option (`shopt -s histverify`), but in a non-interactive shell, that seems to make the history expansion a null-op.

Comment: I had the same thought, but after testing, this doesn't provide working history expansion in a script. However, I can't imagine the use-case for this. History expansion is to ease interactive use.

Comment: I made two mistakes; `set -H` is `set -o histexpand`, which you also need in addition to `set -o history`.

Comment: in bash4, it complaints ``histcommand`` is invalid... what is the use of it..?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wanted to have this working as well, and I have to tell everybody that the `set -o history ; set -o histexpand` method will **not** work in `bash 4.x`. It's not meant to be used there, anyway, since there are better ways to accomplish this.

First of all, a rather trivial example, just wanting to *execute* `history` in a script: 
(**`bash` 4.x or higher ONLY**)

```
#!/bin/bash -i
history
```

Short answer: it works!!
The spanking new `-i` option stands for **interactive**, and `history` *will* work. But for what purpose?

Quoting Michael H.'s comment from the OP:
*"Although you can enable this, this is bad programming practice. It will make your scripts (...) hard to understand. There is a reason it is disabled by default. Why do you want to do this?"*

Yes, **why**? What is the **deeper sense** of this?
Well, THERE IS, which I'm going to demonstrate in the follow-up section.

My `history` buffer has grown HUGE, while some of those lines are script one-liners, which I really would not want to retype every time. But sometimes, I also want to *alter* these lines a little, because I probably want to give a third parameter, whereas I had only needed two in total before.
So here's an **ideal** way of using the `bash` 4.0+ feature to *invoke* `history`:

```
$ history
 (...)
 <lots of lines>
 (...)
  1234 while IFS='whatever' read [[ $whatever -lt max ]]; do ... ; done < <(workfile.fil)
 <25 more lines>
```

So **1234** from history is *exactly* the line we want. Surely, we could take the **mouse** and move there, chucking the whole line in the primary buffer? But we're on *NIX, so why can't we make our life a bit easier?
This is why I wrote the little script below. Again, this is for `bash` 4.0+ ONLY (but might be adapted for `bash` 3.x and older with the aforementioned `set -o ...` stuff...)

```
#!/bin/bash -i
[[ $1 == "" ]] || history | grep "^\s*$1" | 
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf $i" "}' | tr '\n' '\0'
```

If you save this as `xselauto.sh` for example, you may invoke

```
$ ./xselauto.sh 1234
```

and the contents of `history` line #1234 will be in your **primary buffer**, ready for re-use!
Now if anyone still says "this has no purpose AFAICS" or "who'd ever be needing this feature?" - OK, I won't care. But I would no longer want to live without this feature, as I'm just too lazy to retype complex lines every time. And I wouldn't want to touch the mouse for each marked line from history either, TBH. This is what `xsel` was written for.

BTW, the `tr` part of the pipe is a dirty hack which will prevent the command from being *executed*. For "dangerous" commands, it is **extremely** important to always leave the user a way to **look** before he/she hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to execute it. You *may* omit it, but ... you have been warned.

---

*P.S. This scriptlet is in fact a **workaround**, simulating `!1234` typed on a bash shell. As I could never make the `!` work **directly** in a script (`echo` would never let me reveal the **contents** of history line 1234), I worked around the problem by simply `grep`ing for the line I wanted to copy.*

Comment: You should probably use `!1234:p` to just reveal the contents of the item in history. There are also ways to _grep_ and match lines from history using `!?whatever?:p`, which would show you the content of that history item without executing it.

Comment: And an even better way to do what you are after is to enable `histverify`, so that commands from history are not executed when referred using `!` but rather just pasted into your prompt for you to execute.

Answer (score -2):

History expansion is part of the interactive command-line editing features of a shell, not part of the scripting language. It's not generally available in the context of a script, only when interacting with a (pseudo-)human operator. (pseudo meaning that it can be made to work with things like `expect` or other keystroke repeating automation tools that generally try to play act a human, not implying that any particular operator might be sub-human or anything).

Comment: While I agree that it's not meant to be used in a script, it's not true that its not available.

Comment: That's why I said "not generally available" - you have to do some additional stuff to make it so... And even that depends on what shell - there are some where it's not possible, although they may not be in as widespread use these days...

Comment: @twalberg - The question is tagged bash, so I assume that's the only shell that matters.