# How can I include return codes and the command number in my eshell prompt?

Tags: bash, emacs, eshell

I often have need of a shell while using Emacs. Recently, I have been trying to switch over from `shell` to `eshell`, so that I will be able to use the same commands regardless of platform.

One of the first things I would like to do is customize my prompt to match my `bash` prompt. To do this, I am customizing `eshell-prompt-function`. The only thing I am still missing is the current command count and the last return code. I can do this in `bash` by setting `PS1` to e.g. `\!` and `$?` respectively. I have already tried `(eshell/echo "$?")` for the latter, but it doesn't work (though it works if I execute the command manually in eshell).

**Edit:**
An example of what part of my current `bash` prompt looks like is `[~][501:0]`, where `501` is the current command number (so if I type a command and hit `Enter` it will show `502`), and the `0` is the return code.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098095/3076724) may be helpful, though I don't use emacs, so a bit confused with what you're trying to do. Could you include an example of how you want your `PS1` to appear?

Comment: Edited to add an example. I will take a look at the link in detail a bit later when I get the chance, though at first glance it appears to apply mainly to `bash`, so I'm not sure it will help me in my switch to `eshell`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This puts the return code into the eshell prompt:

```lisp
(setq eshell-prompt-function
      (lambda ()
        (format "[%s][%s] "
                (abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd))
                eshell-last-command-status)))
```

I couldn't find any simple way to put the latest command number into the prompt—and it might be less than useful, since eshell seems to use a ring for command history, so at some point the counter would be stuck at 128, and all the previous prompts would be inaccurate.

Note that you should also update `eshell-prompt-regexp` to match anything that `eshell-prompt-function` could come up with.

Comment: For the count: Define a variable my-eshell-command-count and a function that increments it. Add that hook to the eshell-after-prompt-hook list and implement it in your prompt function. Here's my prompt: http://i.imgur.com/VSiFDDX.png

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks! @JordonBiondo, do you have elisp that creates a command counter like that? If not, I may try to implement it myself at some point, and when I do will post back here.